# Refresh Event in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is it possible to handle F5 button in Backbone? Something like:

```
    events: {
        'click .btn': 'function1'
    }
```

Actually I have problem with destroying models after refresh. I get error, when the method get("title") is invoking. And this is App.js. And I thought to create new function after refresh event.

```
var App = (function () {

    var api = {
        Views: {},
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Content: null,
        Router: null,
        init: function () {
            Backbone.history.start();
            return this;
        }
    };

    var ViewsFactory = {

        view1: function () {
            api.Models.Model1 = new Model1();
            if (!this.View1) {
                this.View1 = new api.Views.View1({
                    el: $(".content"),
                    model: api.Models.Model1
                }).on("trigger1", function () {
                        api.Models.Model1 = this.model;
                        api.Router.navigate("#test", {trigger: true});
                    });
            }
            return this.View1;
        },

        view2: function () {
            api.Collections.Collection1 = new Collection1();
            var test = new Model2({
                title: api.Models.Model1.get("title"),
                collection: api.Collections.Collection1
            });
            return this.View2 = new api.Views.View2({
                el: $(".content"),
                model: test
            });
        }
    };

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "": "view1",
            "test": "view2"
        },

        view1: function () {
            var view1 = ViewsFactory.view1();
            view1.render();
        },


        view2: function () {
            var view2 = ViewsFactory.view2();
            view2.render();
        }

    });

    api.Router = new Router();

    return api;
})();
```

Comment: You mean is it possible to listen to refresh (reload) events in Backbone or you want to trigger page reload from Backbone?

Comment: I have problem with destroying model when I refresh page.

Comment: Yes, your in-memory models are destroyed when you refresh the page. Please extend your question with a code showing the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I handle this by router and "" route.